# Elements switch with mouse wheel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

### What I want to do

*Image when scrolling
Look at the moving sentences on the right.
[image: switch scroll]
Like this, I want to highlight the `<p>` element each time scrolling.
That is, usually it's `opacity: 0.3;`, and when it's scrolled, it switches to `opacity: 1;` sequentially from the top.

[image: like this]

I thought that I could do this using [swiper.js](http://idangero.us/swiper/).

[image: now]
I feel like this now. Please look at the one on the right side this too.
If this slider wrap reaches the height of each `<p>` and stops the scroll with `preventDefault ()`, I thought that the implementation would be as expected.

---

### What I tried

jQuery  ( Unfinished, this doesn't work )

```
$(function() {
  $(".mai").scroll(function() {
    onScroll();
  });
  onScroll();
});

function onScroll() {
  $(".main-p p").each(function(i) {
    $(".main-p p").eq(i).removeClass("hl");    // mean highlight

  var scrPos = $(".main-p p:nth-last-child(2)");
  // I want to be second from the bottom of the "visible range" of .mai, not of <p>

  if(scrPos < active) {
    // If hl (= active) is above the second from the bottom of the range seen in .mai

    $('.mai').scroll(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  } else {
    $('.mai').scroll();
    // I want to return the scroll, but is this correct?
  }

  // I want to put processing to highlight with <p>, next <p>, next <p>..
  $('.main-p .active').addClass('hl');

  });
}
```

---

### Add: Current status

[image: like this]
Please look at the right side.
The highlight is applied as it scroll in the image location on the left.
But doesn't apply if it scroll in the right sentence location.
And like on the way, if it press the slide navigation in the upper left, the image will move to that slide properly, but I would like to highlight the sentences as well. (Swiper is set to synchronize images and texts)

And I found something that looked good about what I said in the second image of this question (In fact "the middle of the frame" is good..). -> [scrollama.js](https://russellgoldenberg.github.io/scrollama/basic/)
I want to do this "Basic" as it is.
It's setting up `nth-child(2)` now, but I want to change that to this.

In other words,
I want to
1) Highlight when it scroll over the right sentence
2) Left and right sync
3) Change `nth-child(2)` to "Basic" of scrollama

I made a fork that added an image and scrollama to the latest answer. Please fork this. -> [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/__R2D2/oag5qyeu/15/)

It has become longer..
Sorry, thank you by all means!

---

### Code

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/__R2D2/dk475qzw/10/)
↑ For some reason code snippets do not work well, so have a look at JSFiddle.
Fullscreen Fiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/__R2D2/dk475qzw/10/embedded/result/).

↓ Here is the code only.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".mai").scroll(function() {
    onScroll();
  });
  onScroll();
});

function onScroll() {
  $(".main-p p").each(function(i) {
    $(".main-p p").eq(i).removeClass("hl");    // mean highlight

  var scrPos = $(".main-p p:nth-last-child(2)");
  // I want to be second from the bottom of the "visible range" of .mai, not of <p>

  if(scrPos < active) {
    // If hl (= active) is above the second from the bottom of the range seen in .mai

    $('.mai').scroll(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  } else {
    $('.mai').scroll();
    // I want to return the scroll, but is this correct?
  }

  // I want to put processing to highlight with <p>, next <p>, next <p>..
  $('.main-p .active').addClass('hl');

  });
}



// Processing of left & right sync with swiper
var swiperCnt = new Swiper('.swiperCnt', {
  direction: 'vertical',
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
    type: 'bullets',
    clickable: 'true',
  },
  keyboard: {
    enabled: true,
  },
  mousewheel: {
    forceToAxis: true,
    invert: true,
  },
  renderBullet: function (index, className) {
    return '<span class="' + className + '">' + (index + 1) + '</span>';
  },
});

var swiperP = new Swiper('.swiperP', {
  direction: 'vertical',
  keyboard: {
    enabled: true,
  },
  mousewheel: {
    forceToAxis: true,
    invert: true,
  },
});

swiperCnt.controller.control = swiperP;
swiperP.controller.control = swiperCnt;
```

```css
/* The corresponding part is at the bottom too. (It is faster to count from the bottom)
(There is a mark in the comment) */
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  background-color: #c6d2dd;
  color: white;
}

.wrap {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  padding: 0 0 0 2.4rem;
}

.right {
  padding: 0 4.7rem 0 6.5rem;
  position: relative;
}

h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
  display: inline;
}

.mission,
.m-p,
.concept,
.c-p,
.what,
.target,.t-p,.main-p,.nb,.nb-p,.period,.p-p,.category,.cg-p,.class,.cl-p,.release,.r-p,.nbb,.per,.cat,.cla,.rel {
  display: inline-block;
}

.title {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  padding: 1.8rem 0 1.7rem 0;
}

.solid-ti {
  border-bottom: .1rem solid white;
  margin: 0 -56.3rem 0 -2.4rem;
}

.solid-mc {
  border-bottom: .1rem solid white;
  margin-left: -2.4rem;
}

.solid-tm {
  border-bottom: .1rem solid white;
  margin-right: -4.7rem;
}

.swiper-pagination {
  top: 6rem;
}

.swiper-container {
  width: 69.3rem;
  height: 49.6rem;
}

.swiper-slide {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.swiper-slide img {
  width: 69.3rem;
}

.swiper-pagination-bullet {
  background: none;
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin-right: .5rem;
  opacity: .3;
}
.swiper-pagination-bullet::before {
  content: '0';
  font-weight: bold;
}
.swiper-pagination-bullet:hover::before {
  content: '1';
  font-weight: bold;
}

.swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
  background: none;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition-duration: .16s;
  opacity: .7;
}
.swiper-pagination-bullet-active::before {
  content: '1';
  font-weight: bold;
}

.mis {
  padding: 2.6rem 0 0.7rem 0;
}

.mission {
  padding-right: 2rem;
}

.con {
  padding-top: 0.7rem;
}

.concept {
  padding-right: 2rem;
}

.what {
  margin: 2rem 1.5rem 2.1rem 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.what > img {
  height: 2rem;
  margin-right: .3rem;
}
.what > img:last-child {
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
.what span {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  border: .1rem solid white;
  border-radius: .3rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  padding: .5rem .4rem .4rem;
}

.tar {
  padding: 2.2rem 0 2rem 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.target {
  padding-right: 1.2rem;
}

.t-p {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.heartbox {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.heartbox div:last-child {
  user-select: none;
}

input {
  opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes rubberBand {
  from {
    transform: scale(1, 1, 1);
  }
  30% {
    transform: scale3d(1.15, 0.75, 1);
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale3d(0.75, 1.15, 1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale3d(1.1, 0.85, 1);
  }
  65% {
    transform: scale3d(0.95, 1.05, 1);
  }
  75% {
    transform: scale3d(1.05, 0.95, 1);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }
}
.heart {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: auto;
  height: 25px;
  fill: #E2E2E2;
}

#fav:checked + label .heart {
  fill: #e23b3b;
  animation: rubberBand 0.8s;
}





/*
 * from here
 */
.mai {
  margin: 2.8rem 0 0 0;
  height: 37.8rem;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
}
.mai::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.main-p {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.hl {
  opacity: 1;
}

/*
 * to here
 */





.▼ {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 1.5rem;
}

.under {
  text-align: right;
  position: absolute;
  right: 4.7rem;
  bottom: 2.7rem;
}

.nbb {
  padding-right: 4.8rem;
}

.nb {
  padding-right: .8rem;
}

.period {
  padding-right: 1.6rem;
}

.top {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  padding: 2.1rem 0 2rem;
  text-align: right;
}

.cat {
  padding-right: 1.4rem;
}

.category {
  padding-right: 1.4rem;
}

.cla {
  padding-right: 1.4rem;
}

.class {
  padding-right: 1.4rem;
}

.rel {
  padding-right: 1.4rem;
}

.release {
  padding-right: 1.4rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.0/css/swiper.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- The corresponding part is at the bottom. (It is faster to count from the bottom)
(There is a mark in the comment) -->

<body class="wrap">

  <div class="left">
    <h1 class="title">title</h1>

    <div class="solid-ti"></div>

    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    <div class="swiper-container swiperCnt">
      <section class="swiper-wrapper imgs">
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img class="work" src="http://placehold.jp/45/1920a6/ffffff/693x350.png?text=1" /></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img class="work" src="http://placehold.jp/45/199fa6/ffffff/693x350.png?text=2" alt="Rollse-killer" /></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img class="work" src="http://placehold.jp/45/a61972/ffffff/693x350.png?text=3" alt="Rollse-data" /></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img class="work" src="http://placehold.jp/45/a6a619/ffffff/693x350.png?text=4" alt="Rollse-image" /></div>
      </section>
    </div>

    <div class="mis">
      <h3 class="mission">MISSION:</h3>
      <p class="m-p">sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample </p>
    </div>

    <div class="solid-mc"></div>

    <div class="con">
      <h2 class="concept">CONCEPT:</h2>
      <p class="c-p">sample sample sample </p>
    </div>

    <div class="what">
      <img src="http://placehold.jp/45/d4d4d4/d4d4d4/28x20.png?text=_" alt="2nd" /><img src="http://placehold.jp/45/d4d4d4/d4d4d4/20x20.png?text=_" alt="ai" /><img src="http://placehold.jp/45/d4d4d4/d4d4d4/20x20.png?text=_" alt="vw" />

      <span>sample</span>
      <span>sample</span>
      <span>sample</span>
      <span>sample</span>
      <span>sample</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    <div class="top">
      <div class="cat">
        <h5 class="category">CATEGORY:</h5>
        <p class="cg-p">sample sample </p>
      </div>

      <div class="cla">
        <h5 class="class">CLASS:</h5>
        <p class="cl-p">sample </p>
      </div>

      <div class="rel">
        <h5 class="release">RELEASE:</h5>
        <p class="r-p">sample </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="heartbox">
      <div class="tar">
        <h3 class="target">TARGET:</h3>
        <p class="t-p">sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample 
        </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="fav" id="fav">
        <label for="fav">
            <svg class="heart" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
            viewBox="0 0 37 32" style="enable-background:new 0 0 37 32;" xml:space="preserve">
            <path class="st0" d="M27,0c-2.5,0-4.9,0.9-6.7,2.6C19.6,3.2,19,4,18.5,4.7C18,4,17.4,3.2,16.7,2.6C14.9,0.9,12.5,0,10,0
            C4.5,0,0,4.5,0,10c0,3.7,1.2,6.7,3.9,9.8c3.9,4.6,13.9,11.6,14.3,11.9c0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.3,0.1s0.2,0,0.3-0.1
            c0.4-0.3,10.4-7.3,14.3-11.9c2.7-3.2,3.9-6.1,3.9-9.8C37,4.5,32.5,0,27,0z"/></svg>
          </label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="solid-tm"></div>





    <!--
from here
-->
    <div class="mai swiper-container swiperP">
    <section class="main-p swiper-wrapper"><p class="active swiper-slide">Here is the relevant part. It can scroll.</p>

<p class="swiper-slide">sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample </p>

<p class="swiper-slide">sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample </p>

<p class="swiper-slide">sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample </p>
<p class="swiper-slide">sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample </p>


<p class="swiper-slide">sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample </p>

<p class="swiper-slide">sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample </p>

<p class="swiper-slide">sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample </p>
<p class="swiper-slide">sample sample sample sample sample sample sample </p>
</section>
    </div>
    <!-- 
to here
-->





    <img src="http://placehold.jp/45/d4d4d4/d4d4d4/14x12.png?text=_" alt="▼" class="▼" width="14" />

    <div class="under">
      <div class="nbb">
        <h4 class="nb">N.B.:</h4>
        <p class="nb-p">sample </p>
      </div>

      <div class="per">
        <h4 class="period">PERIOD:</h4>
        <p class="p-p">sample </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.0/js/swiper.js"></script>
```

Could you please give me a hand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another Update:

[Code Fork](https://jsfiddle.net/48hdop5e/), [Full screen Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/48hdop5e/embedded/result/)

For previous post update, you can check on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/55204036/3)

---

The core code for the right side(text) scroll:

```
  var that;
  var i = 0;
  var j = $(".main-p > p").length - 1;
  $('.mai').bind('mousewheel', function(e) {
    if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0) {
      //scroll down
      i++;
      if (i >= j) {
        i = j;
      }
      if (i <= j) {
        $(".main-p > p").each(function(i) {
          if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            if ($(this).hasClass(i)) {
              if (i < j) {
                that = $(this).next();
              } else {
                that = $(this);
              }
            }
          }
          $(this).removeClass('active');
        });
        $(that).addClass('active');
      }
    } else {
      //scroll up
      i--;
      if (i <= 0) {
        i = 0;
      }
      if (i >= 0) {
        $(".main-p > p").each(function(i) {
          if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            if (i > 0) {
              that = $(this).prev();
            } else {
              that = $(this);
            }
          }
          $(this).removeClass('active');
        });
        $(that).addClass('active');
      }
    }
    swiperCnt.slideTo(i);
    //prevent page fom scrolling
    return false;
  });
```

Explanation: `i++` or `i--` on scroll down / up with the if `>=` / `>` or `<=` / `<` is detecting out of bound or not. And respond respectively. [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) and [`.prev`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) is used for highlighting previous or next element on scroll.

For left side(img) scroll:

```
swiperCnt.on('scroll', function() {
  onScroll();
});
```

which execute `onScroll()` function.

Comment: Wow it's highlighted! Thank you!
When I scroll, I want to switch the highlight on the screen on the right WITHOUT switching to like the "slide screen". How should I do? (Refer to the first gif of the question)

Comment: @POP Can you check update if that's what you want? ありがとう

Comment: Whoa thank you very much!
Yes, like this!
A little more, but now it is applied highlight only when you scroll the image, but can you apply the same by scrolling the text on the right?
The current situation has been added to the question. Please look by all means.
And I'm so happy you used Japanese :D むきゅーってなまえ、かわいいね (= The name むきゅー(Mukyuu) is cute) :)

Comment: @POP Like this https://jsfiddle.net/9b3acfq5/ ? Or do you want the text to be scrollable too? Sync with the left part?

Comment: Yes it's both. I forgot to make the text scrollable. I made it possible to scroll the previous fiddle. -> [here](https://jsfiddle.net/__R2D2/vkpdurgj/1/)

Comment: It have returned to the beginning..
I want to be able to scroll the right side too with the Update answer.

Comment: Wow thank you so much!!
As for scrollama, I would like to trial and error again.
I'm really thankful to you xD

Comment: It's been a while, Mukyuu! I put `<br>` between `<p>`, but `<br>` has ended up disappeared. Like this: [gif-link](https://i.imgur.com/RKGgQ45.gifv) How can I prevent `<br>` from disappearing?

Comment: Possibly caused by another CSS styling. Can you post fiddle/snippet which demonstrated the issue? You can check on forked fiddle with 2 `<br>`: https://jsfiddle.net/zeuhavqt/

Comment: I edited JSFiddle. 1) delete `main-p {white-space: pre-wrap;}` in CSS.  2) add some `<br>` in HTML.  -> [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/__R2D2/cxeh6t3z/6/) But, even though the code is exactly the same as my local code, `<br>` is functioning properly in JSFiddle..  So, I uploaded my actual local situation [here](https://mqs2.com/broblem/br.html). like this..

Comment: I see try adding `white-space: pre-line;` in section class`main-p max-inner`. Might help you to learn about [`white-space`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp)

Comment: Thank you.
I could Leave line blank with `pre-line`. But while I was looking into it, the root cause was found. It seems that the `line-height` of text seems to overlap with `<br>`, `<br>` just looked like disappeared.
So, by adding `<br>` the same as the text: `line-height: 1.8;`, I was able to Leave line blank properly.
Thank you so much for your help!! x)